# How we can connect react js with django?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, django, server

How we can connect react js with django without installing node js?

Code of connect django with react without install nodejs server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create APIs in your Django backend and hit those APIs with **fetch** in your react application and can interact with the Django server.

You can also install the **django-webpack-loader** package, which will help you integrate React with Django.

In your Django application settings include the **django-webpack-loader** package and configure it to point to your React application.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize https://django-webpack-loader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Granted you will still need node to build the react app

Comment: Link only answers don’t typically offer that much help. Enrich your answer by adding details as to why it will solve/help